# Facebook application under a Fans page TAB?

Tags: facebook

I managed to build a basic IFrame application, using the Graph API. I wanted to be able to load this application via Fans Pages' tabs - Only to realize Facebook doesn't like the idea of using iframes under said tabs. (I know of a workaround, which is not acceptable...)

So I gather I should start over doing it a Static FBML Application, and not IFrame - for meeting my tabs requirement. My question is... where do I start? How do I auth a specific application?

any helpful references/guides will be very appreciated.
(avoid links to Facebook's documentation, they're sad.)

Thanks,
Doori Bar

Comment: Are you talking about tab application or regular application? Tab application doesn't have to be authorized, only your main app.

Comment: @serg555: You tell me :) , 1. I would like my application to be able to sit at a fans page' tab. 2. I would like the application to be able to ask for extended permissions ... which application do I need?

Comment: The thing is tab application is pretty limited. It is intended for displaying some information about the user, who installed it to their profile, not about the visitor. What kind of tab are you trying to create (what will it do)?

Comment: @serg555: thanks for the fast response, I would... 1. user clicks on a tab. 2. the application sees he's a new user, and show him a breif description of the app, and asks him for extended permission to send publish to his stream. 3. the user auth the application and grant permission, and now the application is allowed to publish to his stream.

Comment: And this has to be in the tab, not in the regular app? The problem is that tab app doesn't know who is visiting it right away, it knows only who installed it. Visitor information is sent only after they "interact" with the tab. What you described is what regular app is for. I can give you an example how to do that in regular app, but not sure about tabbed app.

Comment: Also which server side language are you using for those app pages (php?)

Comment: @serg555: I already did it as a regular application, "IFrame application" using the Graph API! ... the problem is, my goal is to use it strictly under TABS. I wouldn't mind the limitation of knowing only who installed it, but where do I begin? how do I ask for extended permissions via a Static FBML - to my desired application?

Comment: (just noticed your following question) , Yes - I used php for the iframe based application.

Comment: Tab app cannot exist without main app. Tab app is just a subpage of the main app that can be installed to user profiles. User authorizes your main app, and then he can install tab app to his profile. You don't ask users to authorize your tab app and don't ask to give it any permissions. Your main app is responsible for that.

Comment: @serg555: So it's a dead-end for me? I guess my only nasty and shameful solution, is to use the on-click workaround, to bypass facebook's limitation on IFrames. That way I'll launch it inside a page's tab. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: I know fb docs are not good, but they are better than nothing. You can read about tabbed aps here, maybe it will clear things up a bit: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Tabbed_Profile

Comment: I still don't clearly understand what you are trying to achieve. If you want to have tab app without regular app - it isn't possible to my knowledge. User can install a tab only after authorizing your main app. So I don't see why would you want to ask for permissions in a tab if user already granted them to your main app? Your main app is supposed to ask for permissions, and tabbed up is supposed to showing some information about a user who installed it (or just some user independent info)

Comment: This is the iframe workaround I wanted to avoid: http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/adding-iframes-to-facebook-application-2010-static-fbml/ This would obviously solve my issue, because I'll be able to fire my iframe-application from inside a tab. But I've read the link you gave me, honestly it's the first I've seen the term: "application tab". It says a user may AUTH an app, can it auth with extended permissions? (that's what I need)

Comment: @serg555: I'll try to explain one more time the current behavior of my IFrame application: 1. a user visits the link: http://apps.facebook.com/<APP-NAME> ... the application asks him for extended permissions... the user agrees. I want that exact behavior, instead from: apps.facebook.com/APP... I want it inside a Fans Page TAB. Now it makes more sense?

Comment: Nope, sorry :) Because: 1. You can't have tab app without main app (is this what you want?). 2. User authorizes your main app, not your tab app. Anyway, let me post an example how to authorize and ask for permissions from FBML for a regular app. You can try to fit it into your tab app.

Comment: I don't really understand what's a main app? if a user who visits the fans page sees that tab, can he grant permission to this main app?

Very appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't think he can, because tab app doesn't know who is visiting it. It knows only who installed it. If tab is installed to a fan page it knows only information about that fan page (fan page id), not about the visitor (no visitor id known). `apps.facebook.com/<APP-NAME>` is your main app. Your tab app would be `apps.facebook.com/<APP-NAME>/tab.php`. Tab app is not intended to be a full scale app, it is intended to be a small part of your main app that can be installed to user profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to prompt a user to authorize an app from FBML:

```
<fb:if-is-app-user> 
    <fb:else>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key={$fbApiKey}&v=1.0">Authorize This App</a> 
    </fb:else> 
</fb:if-is-app-user>
```

How to ask for extra permissions:

First you will need to check from PHP FB Api if user has granted you required permissions, if not, then pass some flag to FBML to display this code:

```
<fb:if-is-app-user> 
    <?php 
        if($noPermissionFlag) {
            echo '<fb:prompt-permission perms="publish_stream,email">Would you like to allow this app posting to your wall?</fb:prompt-permission>';
        }
    ?>
</fb:if-is-app-user>
```

That's how it would work in a regular FBML canvas app. Not sure about putting this in tab.

Comment: So bottom line, what you're saying... I did choose the right path - IFrame Application. Because there is no alternative to make it happen as a "tab". So my options are: 1. use the iframe workaround, for using my iframe application inside a tab. or 2. making a tab which has a link, asking the user to goto my http://apps.facebook.com/<app-name> ... right? (that's a tough call)

Comment: @Doori Bar: You never said what exactly your app is doing besides asking for permissions. Why would someone want to install it to their profile anyway? The workflow is like this: 1. User goes to your main app, authorizes it, grants permissions. 2. If he likes it, he can install a tab app to his profile (tab app is a just a subpage of main app, /tab.php). If I visit a user who installed your tab app and I like it - I go to your main app, authorize it, grant permission and install your tab app to my profile.

Comment: 555: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you. Without you elaborating the manner, I would've wasted days before I'd come to realize I'm actually going nowhere. Regards my application, it's actually an INFORMATIVE application, which has the ability of publishing contents to the users who granted extended permissions. (the app gives contents)

Comment: @Doori Bar: You are welcome. Just consider tab application to be "my profile" page of your main application. Lets say your app is posting news on user selected topics. I would make a tab that displays news that were selected by the user who installed it. If a visitor likes what he sees and wants his own news - instead of asking him to authorize your app and subscribe to his own news topics right in someone else's tab (again not sure if it is even possible) - I would rather forward him to main app where he can personalize his own tab.